# How to create a sandbox payment in a currency other then USD

Tags: square-connect

I have set up the Square Payment Example App as explained here: https://pub.dev/packages/square_in_app_payments

As well as the backend service on Heroku as explained here:
https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-flutter-plugin/blob/master/example/take_a_payment.md

My Square account is setup in Australia, therefore it can only accept payments in AUD. 
However, I don't seem to be able to create a sandbox payment that is not USD. 
I have replaced every occurrence of "USD" with "AUD" in the example app, but that does not seem to change anything.

This is the output from Heroku:

```
{
 "code": "INVALID_VALUE",
 "detail": "This business can only process payments in AUD but amount was provided in USD.",
 "field": "order.line_items[0].base_price_money.currency",
 "category": "INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR"
 }
]
```

This happens if the request is send from the app as well as when I copy the nonce and use it in a curl request.

How do I change the currency that is used in the request?

Comment: Most of the Flutter In-App Payments is client-side. The setting to switch currencies happens on the backend.You would need to edit your Heroku app to change the `createPayment` request to use `AUD` instead. You can do this by forking the Heroku app and editing it and then pushing it to Heroku.